# Does it make sense to do Scaling with Ordinal Number in Data Mining

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

in a data mining regression problem, there is a column named 'Quality', and the value are:

```
['Excellent','Good','Average','Fair','Poor']
```

so I think 'Good' is better than 'Average', and I change them into ordinal number with mapping:

```
'Excellent' : 5 
'Good' : 4 
'Average' : 3 
'Fair' : 2 
'Poor' : 1
```

so my question is:

After I change value into number, can I do scaling with mean and variance about this ordinal number, for example, StandardScaler with pandas

Comment: This question is not related to programming, better ask it at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered.

Encoding ordinals as integers is a *heuristic*. You may get better results with -100,-10,0,5,10 for example, or a scaled version thereof. Or it might not matter at all!

If you want to know if this is necessary, you need to investigate a statistical model of your data and process. This qill be hard, and you will have to do this yourself (as we don't have your data, and problem, and enough time).

Comment: thanks for reply, and you mentioned the numbers: -100,-10,0,5,10, can you give some clue why you are using these numbers, do you have some pattern? thank you again

Comment: If e.g. `Poor` is very rare, it may be better to emphasize it's effect. The values are likely not uniformly distributed.